# Display validation error for multiple input fields within one FormItem

Tags: antd, react-final-form

I've implemented a control that contains 3 `select` fields (day, month, year) in order to enter a date.
When all 3 fields are given, the component creates a `Moment` object and sets the value in my form, which then triggers the validation. (I am using react-final-form for the form validation part but it's probably not that necessary to know).

If the validation fails, I want to highlight all 3 fields in red and display the error message below the fields.

Given that I have multiple select fields within one `FormItem`, the error message can obviously not been displayed. 
What I would like to know is whether there is a way to programmatically set the error status of the `select` component (NOT the `FormItem`) or somehow set the error style on the individual `selects`?

Here is some pseudo code just to illustrate how how the `FormItem` is constructed.

```
<FormItem label={label}>
  <>
     <Select></Select> <-- To be marked/highlighted as error if validation fails
     <Select></Select> <-- To be marked/highlighted as error if validation fails
     <Select></Select> <-- To be marked/highlighted as error if validation fails
     ...Here I will display the error message...
  </>
</FormItem>
```

Comment: Yes, you can, the problem is that you using 3rd party validator when you have a built-in within the Form component: https://ant.design/components/form/, moreover I guess you make your form controlled which is not recommended, never the less - this question is regarding to  `react-final-form` and not `antd`

Comment: Also, you missing a producible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks @DennisVash Actually, I found the mistake. I didn't sent the "touched" flag for that particular field. That's why my condition to display the error (meta.error && meta.touched ? "error" : "") never returned "error". You are right that I am mixing here 2 components. But I found the react-final-form more suitable for validation than the AntD form. So I decided to use the AntD UI components and implement the forms/validations using react-final-form. So far, the integration works pretty well.
Can you elaborate on "you make your form controlled which is not recommended"? Thanks!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html, you "always" should prefer uncontrolled when possible, for maintenance, readability, and scalability. `antd` has uncontrolled version of `Form` with `Form.create`. It is out of the scope of this question, you should just ask another one for more insights then mine.

Comment: Ah that's what you mean. But your comment is contradicting to what it's stated on that site. "In most cases, we recommend using controlled components to implement forms." Anyway, since I use react-final-form, I don't really have control over it anyway.

Comment: “To implement forms” you got antd form already implemented, and I talked about this Form and not your 3rd party library. Anyway good luck. Cheers.